# Convert string of data points separated by comma to List<int> in C#

Tags: c#

How to get `List<int>` value from string value separated by comma like below

```
string s={ 23,234,0,12,43,6,34,45,7 }
```

In this case:

```
      string[] s = data.Split(',');

      List<int32> li = new List<int32>();

        foreach (String sout in s)
        {
            li.Add(Convert.ToInt32(sout));
        }
```

but getting error like "Input string was not in a correct format." @ "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: How is your data look like ?

Comment: 21,230,3,200,7,9,0,3,7,0,35,8,21,230,6,0,60,8,71,102,2,0,37,4,21,230,3,200... like this I have 540 data points..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
string s="23,234,0,12,43,6,34,45,7";

string[] s = data.Split(',');

List<int32> li = new List<int32>();
        foreach (String sout in s)
        {
            int i;
            if (Int32.TryParse(sout, out i))
                li.Add(i);
        }
```

Comment: Please also explain if you don't fire ArgumentExceptions how can you tell the program functions the way it's supposed to function? Don't ommit exceptions like a newly "on error resume next" scenario unless intended.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myString = "23,234,0,12,43,6,34,45,7";
string[] myStrings = myString.Split(',');
var myList = new List<string>();
myList = myStrings.ToList();
var myListInt = new List<int>();
myListInt = myList.Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s)).ToList();
```

Or even you can use *Regex*

```
var myString = "23,234,0,12,43,6,34,45,7";
var matches = Regex.Matches(myString, @"[^,]+");
```

You can iterate `matches` in the `foreach` statement.

Comment: actually your code is working properly, but if I use other string data red from text file getting same error   string data = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\dell e6400\Desktop\zzz.txt");
            string[] myStrings = data.Split(',');
            var myList = new List<string>();
            myList = myStrings.ToList();
            var myListInt = new List<int>();
            myListInt = myList.Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s)).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

This works like a charm...

```
var str = "23,234,0,12,43,6,34,45,7";
List<Int32> integers = new List<String>(str.Split(',')).ConvertAll(s => Convert.ToInt32(s));
```

Pls mark it as answer if it helps..

Comment: its working dude but try it out=>         string data = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\dell e6400\Desktop\zzz.txt");
            List<Int32> integers = new List<String>(data.Split(',')).ConvertAll(s => Convert.ToInt32(s));